No metadata for "User" was found
Terminal Error HTTP Response Error
I'm having an error when i try to create an user using TypeORM and Nest.js
The error says: No metadata for "User" was found.
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.
I've tried everything i've seen that could be, downgraded TypeORM, changed the DataSource, changed the dir of enitities.
REPO: https://github.com/DevGabrielSoares/movie_catalog
to reproduce error:

npm install
docker-compose up
http POST localhost:3001/accounts



There is an issue with your UniqueEntityID type, which converts the id to an invalid type

In create-user.ts, you referred to the wrong model without using the Entity in the @InjectRepository method


@InjectRepository(UserEntity)

In your user.ts file, the static create method return a nested user object inside the user object


to avoid that you can simply used a user object
 const user = {
      name,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    };

and for saving user to the db used save method. If you used create

create - Creates a new instance of User. Optionally accepts an object literal with user properties which will be written into newly created user object

Repository Create API
instead of that, use save method

In the database.module.ts file change entities: [UserEntity, MovieEntity]

In the http.module.ts file, change TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity, MovieEntity])


Because both of these modules refer to the Entities in Typeorm
With All changes, I created a Pull Request for your repository. Pull Request

Thats it!! Thank you so much man!

can you mark this as the answer

i think the entities you input should be the entity in your TypeormModule.forRoot
  import { User } from '@/infra/database/entities/user.entity'

 ...
 entities: [User, Movie],

